# How to use HasManyThrough Relation in laravel datatable

Tags: laravel-5, datatables

I have three tables i am able to use relation between 2 tables easily. But when i am trying to access values from third table i mean trying to use hasManyThrough relation it is showing me always error. Do you have any idea how i can get value of third table column using middle table relation with first and last table.

System details

Linux
PHP 7

Laravel 5.3

Laravel-Datatables Latest Version

```js
$('#mms-table').DataTable({
    processing : true,
    serverSide: true,
    lengthMenu: [10,25,50,100],
    order: [[1,'desc']],
    ajax: '{!! url(LaravelLocalization::getCurrentLocale()."/admin/contact-management/contact-data") !!}',
    columns: [
        { data: 'merchant.bank.name', name: 'merchant.bank_id', orderable: true },
        { data: 'merchant.merchant_id', name: 'merchant.merchant_id', orderable: true },
        { data: 'merchant.merchant_name', name: 'merchant.merchant_name', orderable: true },
        { data: 'contact.name', name: 'contact.name', orderable: true },
        { data: 'contact.email', name: 'contact.email', orderable: true },
        { data: 'city', name: 'city', orderable: true },
        { data: 'agent.name', name: 'agent.name', orderable: true },
        { data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false},
    ],
    dom: 'Blfrptip',
    buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'colvis',text: 'Show/Hide Columns'
            }
    ],
    oLanguage: {
            sProcessing: "<img height='80' width='80' src='{{ url('public/images/loading.gif') }}' alt='loader'/>"
    },
    initComplete: function () {
        this.api().columns().every(function () {
            var column = this;
            var input = document.createElement("input");
            $(input).appendTo($(column.footer()).empty())
            .on('change', function () {
                column.search($(this).val(), false, false, true).draw();
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: What had you tried so far?

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: I have added the code above